# How do I query my django model's manyToMany field?

Tags: django, django-queryset

I am working on a django app to manage my hockey pool, and I am having trouble defining a query. the relevant models look like so:

```
class Player(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Team(models.Model):
    pool = models.ForeignKey(Pool)
    manager = models.ForeignKey(User)
    active_players = models.ManyToMany(Player)
```

In one of my views, I want to go through each player, and find out if that player is owned by someone. If they are not, they are added to a list that is passed to the template.

I have everything working except the query for checking if their is a team with a certain pool.id that has a certain player in their active_player list. I have this so far:

```
players = Player.objects.all()
for player in players:
    teams = Team.objects.filter(???not sure what to put here???)
    #and then something here to check if teams is empty
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have the player, then you can access the teams that player is assigned to simply with:

```
player.team_set.all()
```

If you just want to get a list of players not on a team, it's even easier:

```
Player.objects.filter(team__isnull=True)
```

Comment: I dont think this will work. My player model does not have a team field. the players on each team are kept in  the manytomany field active_players in the Team model.

Comment: `team` is implicit. When you set up a M2M, django automatically creates a related manager for you at `<model>_set`. This is called the "related name", and it can be customized with the `related_name` property. And, whatever the related name is (minus the `_set` if it was automatically added) can also be used in filtering as well. Just try it.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. It makes sense to me now. Very cool.

Answer (score 0):

Give something like this a try:

```
without_team = []
for player in Player.objects.all():
    if not Team.objcets.filter(active_players__in=[player]):
        without_team.append(player)
```

Not tested code snippet